# How to plot several graphs one after another

Tags: r, plot, 3d, line

I would like to plot my graphs in one 3d coordinate system. I it possible to plot these graphs in series (one after another) without defining a z coordinate.

```
x = 460:650
y1 = rnorm(191, 5, 2)
y2 = rnorm(191, 4, 1)
y3 = rnorm(191, 2, 0.8)

plot(x, y1, col = "red", type = "l")
lines(x, y2, col = "green", add = T)
lines(x, y3, col = "blue", add = T)
```

Here is an example data set. At the moment I plot my graphs all in the same 2d coordinate system. I want them in the same 3d coordinate system. Meaning the red curve should be the foremost and the blue curve the last curve. All these 3 plots can have the same distance from each other.

Comment: How do you expect to define depth/distance between each line without defining z-coordinate?

Comment: Just by adding them stepwise?

Comment: If you want "red" front-most, then plot it last. The layers are plotted with the most-recent up-front, whether points, lines, or something else.

Comment: I think stefan is looking for something like this: https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/3D-Line-Chart.png

Comment: @Monk. Yes exactly.

Comment: Looks like this might be helpful then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327692/how-to-make-3d-plots-with-categorical-data-in-r

Comment: Maybe you could define a factor level per y variable and plot that factor on z axis. Otherwise plotting 3d without defining 3rd dimension sounds impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all types of ugly but, I think it does what you want. Adapted from https://plot.ly/r/3d-line-plots/.

```
library(plotly) 
x = rep(460:650,3) 
y1 = rnorm(191, 5, 2)
y2 = rnorm(191, 4, 1)
y3 = rnorm(191, 3, 1)
z = c(rep(1,191),rep(2,191),rep(3,191))
z <- ordered(z, levels=c('1', '2', '3'))

y_all<-(c(y1,y2,y3))
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y_all, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines', color = ~z)
```

As others mentioned, no you cannot plot in z-space without defining some z. Here, you just need a categorical z to set things against and then you can tell `plot_ly()` to format it "nicely"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I have decided to define z as well. You are right. Otherwise it is a bit inelegant.

```
data = data.frame(x = c(460, 465, 470, 475, 480, 485, 490, 495, 500, 505, 510, 515, 520, 525, 530, 535, 540, 545, 550,
                        460, 465, 470, 475, 480, 485, 490, 495, 500, 505, 510, 515, 520, 525, 530, 535, 540, 545, 550,
                        460, 465, 470, 475, 480, 485, 490, 495, 500, 505, 510, 515, 520, 525, 530, 535, 540, 545, 550),
                  time = c(rep(0, 19), rep(0.1, 19), rep(0.2, 19)), values = c(80,104,138,188,212,247,287,324,359,366,393,417,397,371,364,345,321,319,295,
                                                                               80,104,138,188,212,247,287,324,359,366,393,417,397,371,364,345,321,319,295,
                                                                               80,104,138,188,212,247,287,324,359,366,393,417,397,371,364,345,321,319,295))
lines3D(data$x, data$time, data$values)
```

When I use the lines3D function how can I label and define the axes? At the moment the axes are only labelled with x, y and z.

Comment: `lines3D()` takes a variety of additional inputs including `xlab` and `ylab` which can be used to define axis labels. You can see this list of additional options by typing `?lines3D()` into R and reading the help file.